# Is this inequality about conditional expectations and martingales true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be a square integrable discrete-time Markov martingale, that is, $E[Z|X]=X$, $E[Y|X]=X$, $E[Z|X,Y]=E[Z|Y]=Y$. Let $U$ be a square integrable random variable independent from $(X,Y,Z)$. Is it true that

$$ E[ (Z- E[Z|X, Z+U])^2 ] \leq  E[ (Z- E[Z|Y, Z+U])^2 ] + E[ (Y- E[Y|X, Y+U])^2 ]$$

This inequality means that the error that one makes when estimation $Z$ based on $X$ and a noisy version of $Z$ is smaller than the sum of the error that one makes when estimation $Z$ based on $Y$ and a noisy version of $Z$ and the error that one makes when estimation $Y$ based on $X$ and a noisy version of $Y$.

The inspiration for this inequality is that, if we remove the noisy terms $Z+U$ and $Y+U$ everywhere, the inequality is true since $$ E[ (Z- E[Z|X])^2 ] = E[ (Z- X)^2 ] \leq E[ (Z- Y)^2 ] + E[ (Y- X)^2 ]$$

Now, adding the noisy terms $Z+U$ and $Y+U$ inside the conditioning is making all the estimates (the conditional expectations) better, i.e., the errors are smaller. Since $U$ is common to all terms and is independent from the martingale, we are making them better "in the same way" (hand waving). This is the intuition behind

$$ E[ (Z- E[Z|X, Z+U])^2 ] \leq  E[ (Z- E[Z|Y, Z+U])^2 ] + E[ (Y- E[Y|X, Y+U])^2 ]$$

Any thoughts/proof?

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are some problems with this conjecture.

As an example, consider the following scenario. Assume $X$ is always $1$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $\{0, 2\}$, and $Z \sim N(Y, 1)$. Furthermore, $U$ is uniformly distributed in $\{0, 1\}$.

Then the second term on RHS in your conjecture is zero, since $Y + U$ uniquely determines $Y$. So we are left with
$$E[(Z - E[Z | Z + U])^2] \leq E[(Z - E[Z | Y, Z + U])^2].$$
Or
$$E[Z^2] - E[E[Z | Z + U]^2] \leq E[Z^2] - E[E[Z | Y, Z + U]^2].$$
Or
$$E[(E[Z | Z + U] - E[Z | Y, Z + U])^2] \leq 0$$
which is not true since $E[Z | Z + U] \neq E[Z | Y, Z + U]$.

Comment: I see where the problem is. We are not supposed to know what $Y$ is by looking at $Y+U$ since it's supposed to be a noisy version of $Y$. That's because we have too much freedom on $U$. We must impose that $U$ is a continuous random variable on $\mathbb R$. Like this, it is impossible to guess $Y$ from $Y+U$ for instance. Under this new scenario, what do you think about the conjecture?

Comment: I feel that this assumption won't help much, since we can replace discrete random variables by continuous distributions supported in a small neighbor of the discrete values.

Comment: That's why I said on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I still feel the conjecture shouldn't be true. Say U is uniform in [-0.01,0.01] union [0.99, 1.01], and Y is uniform in [-0.01, 0.01] union [1.99, 2.01]. Then even though we cannot guess Y from U + Y, we would have a very good idea, so the second term on RHS would be close to 0.

Comment: When I say on $\mathbb R$, I mean supported on $\mathbb R$, like a Gaussian for instance.

Comment: Well then you can replace U([-0.01, 0.01]) with N(0, 0.01) and such.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but all the terms would be very close to $0$ if we choose $U$ to have a very small variance, not only the second term in the RHS.

Comment: U is a hybrid of the N(0, 0.01) and N(1, 0.01), so it still have a large variance.

Comment: What do you mean by hybrid? A convolution?

Comment: $U$ follows $N(0, 0.01)$ with probability $0.5$, and $N(1, 0.01)$ with probability $0.5$.

Comment: Or you can say that $U$ is the convolution of $N(0, 0.1)$ and the uniform distribution on $\{0, 1\}$.